# replaceText working in one instance but not in another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-forms

The script is triggered when a Google form is submitted and then auto-fills a Google doc.

It worked perfectly before I added `var servicesPTY = e.values[117];` and replaced all the placeholders perfectly. But as soon as I add it then the executions indicator show *completed* but no documents are produced anymore. The document has placeholders that look like this: **{{servicesPTY}} {{regNumberPTY}} {{tradingNamePTY}}**

And the code looks like this:

```
function myFormSubmitPTY(e) {

  var regNumberPTY = e.values[112];
  var taxNumberPTY = e.values[111];
  var tradingNamePTY = e.values[113];
  var servicesPTY = e.values[117];

var file = DriveApp.getFileById("16OwyBIZAD2pwkuUXZnYSj-9WB6ObGGRXiEjDLa1tcjw");

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1kogpJdxHLwuEhbVyh2oiIgTPH0SNac2m");

  var copy = file.makeCopy(tradingNamePTY, folder);

  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());

  var body = doc.getBody();

  if (type == "PTY (LTD)") {

  body.replaceText("{{servicesPTY}}",servicesPTY);
  body.replaceText("{{regNumberPTY}}", regNumberPTY);
  body.replaceText("{{tradingNamePTY}}", tradingNamePTY);


  doc.saveAndClose();
  }
}
```

Comment: var type is identified, I just left it out to save space

Comment: What you're saying doesn't seem plausible. Provide [mcve]

Comment: Please, check `servicesPTY` value and update your answer. Although, if I am right in what I am thinking about, you should've received a failed execution. The same holds true if you would just exceed the quota. Given the fact that Cooper's answer below also seems to suggest the issue not reproducible, please, give us more info

Comment: The ```servicesPTY``` value looks like this **Tax Return, Supporting Documents, Objections, Payroll, EMP501, Advisory Services, Appeals, Business TAX Returns, Provisional TAX Return, IT14SD, Specialised TAX, Financial Statements, Company Registration, CIPC Annual Returns - PTY (LTD), CIPC Ammedments, CIPC PTY (LTD) / CC Registration**

Comment: I still need to replace the commas with new lines as soon as I get it to work...

Comment: Could you share a sample doc where you see this behavior? I don't see anything wrong with your code. Maybe the data that you receive is not correct, or you miss type the placeholder.

Comment: I changed the code to run on these sample docs so if you complete a form for a PTY (LTD) then you will see what I mean:   [sample doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Kf-Nss5LvLngboNSQNnnAHjLv5WgHqs5vEjhYw9PbBk/edit?usp=sharing)   [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SAV5SH2bcooXa7q0XuL0PJAsQ_4UMvNVVhdI6UY-Hqo/edit?usp=sharing)   [sample form] (https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfQk9hPDkSP6vmj2eqAajXBCx4Euqb157qODXOisAVMKzs6-w/viewform)    [sample folder](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/198WaEWlrt_ccoM1DjQcHf6UfgSavkuDS?usp=sharing)

Comment: My brain is fried on this, can someone please help me?

Comment: @Raserhin will these sample docs work?

Comment: Thank you, but the only thing I see after making the form is that there is nothing created in the folder, I still don't see any logs of the file. Neither the code that was made for this execution.  Could you maybe log the value of `servicesPTY` I suspect that the value may be `null` or `undefined` and that may be throwing an error.

Comment: The value of `servicesPTY` is a long string that includes commas, brackets, hyphens, front slashes etc. One value looks like this: **Tax Return, Supporting Documents, Objections, Payroll, EMP501, Advisory Services, Appeals, Business TAX Returns, Provisional TAX Return, IT14SD, Specialised TAX, Financial Statements, Company Registration, CIPC Annual Returns - PTY (LTD), CIPC Ammedments, CIPC PTY (LTD) / CC Registration**

Comment: Inside the Script Editor I clicked on File and then Share but then it doesn't give me any confirmation or error when I do so I'm not sure if it worked and if the script  is actually shared or not

Comment: This string work as normal with the `replaceText`, the problem has to come from somewhere else. Seriously, try to log the value of `servicesPTY` before replacing to make sure is not `null` or `undefined`. That's the only thing that could be right now. The string itself is not a problem for the funciton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must have deselected the trigger for PTY. When I looked at the stackdriver logs I noticed PTY had none. Must have happened in the early hours of the morning. Thanks though. You guys put me on the right track

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
function testmyFormSubmit() {
  var e={values:["one","two","three","four"]};
  myFormSubmitPTY(e);
}

var type="PTY (LTD)";//global

function myFormSubmitPTY(e) {
  var regNumberPTY = e.values[0];
  var taxNumberPTY = e.values[1];
  var tradingNamePTY = e.values[2];
  var servicesPTY = e.values[3];
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById("fileid");
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folderid");
  var copy = file.makeCopy(tradingNamePTY, folder);
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
  var body = doc.getBody();
  if (type=="PTY (LTD)") {
    body.replaceText("{{servicesPTY}}",servicesPTY);
    body.replaceText("{{regNumberPTY}}", regNumberPTY);
    body.replaceText("{{tradingNamePTY}}", tradingNamePTY);
    doc.saveAndClose();
  }
}
```

file name: three

pattern order:

{{servicesPTY}}

{{regNumberPTY}}

{{tradingNamePTY}}

output order:

four

one

three

Comment: I can't get this one to work, but I'm not sure what to do with the pattern order and output order. Do I need to define the ["one","two","three","four"] ?